# How to get caption to line break in scrbook?

Tags: captions, koma-script, wrapfigure, scrbook

So I have a large project and one of the pictures is quite small, but has a very large caption.  Currently the caption just extends into the page of text and all of the solutions I have seen for getting it to line-break have not succeeded.
The text for the caption is about 3 inches wide, and the picture I am using is only about 1.5 inches.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\setlength{\belowcaptionskip}{-15pt}

\begin{document}
\begin{wrapfigure}{l}{0.3\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{32.jpg}
\caption*{\texttt{\scalebox{.8}[1.0]{Doodle, "X-ray view with \protect    \\mutilated horse head”}}}
\end{wrapfigure}

\end{document}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: remove the `\scalebox{.8}[1.0]{` which is stopping the linebreaking and distorting the text.

Comment: Any way around that?  I know it distorts the text, but the person I'm doing this for insisted.

Comment: Really if you are going to do that to the text you may as well let the text stick out the margin either way any attempt at reasonable typography is lost. What is the intention of the scalebox, there must be an alternative?

Comment: Essentially the font I'm using, in his mind, needs to be more 'condensed' and 'tighter'.  Fortunately, the font in this case doesn't look too bad when you use scalebox (normally it does).  I wouldn't ever bother with it myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want to scale the text in this strange way, you can use a `\parbox` inside the `\scalebox`.

```
\caption*{\texttt{\scalebox{.8}[1.0]{\parbox{\linewidth}{\raggedright
Doodle, "X-ray view with mutilated horse head”}}}}
```

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\setlength{\belowcaptionskip}{-15pt}

\begin{document}
\begin{wrapfigure}{l}{0.3\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{example-image}
\caption*{\texttt{\scalebox{.8}[1.0]{\parbox{\linewidth}{\raggedright
  Doodle, "X-ray view with mutilated horse head”}}}}
\end{wrapfigure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Alright that worked.  I know it's sort of strange, but if you just read the caption you can tell it already is.